# How to add x-offset to text pattern with every x-step? (itext)

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating a text pattern within a rectangle with the following snippet:

```
var canvas = m_writer.DirectContent;

float fillTextSize = 6.0f;
string filltext = "this is the fill text!";
float filltextWidth = m_dejavuMonoBold.GetWidthPoint(filltext, fillTextSize);

PdfPatternPainter pattern = canvas.CreatePattern(px, py, filltextWidth, fillTextSize);
pattern.BeginText();
pattern.SetTextMatrix(0, 0);
pattern.SetTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL);
pattern.SetRGBColorStroke(190, 190, 190);
pattern.SetRGBColorFill(190, 190, 190);
pattern.SetFontAndSize(m_dejavuMonoBold, 6.0f);
pattern.ShowText(filltext);
pattern.EndText();

canvas.Rectangle(px, py, pw, ph);
canvas.SetPatternFill(pattern);
canvas.Fill();
```

The fill text is repeated regularly. I want to add with every printed line of the pattern to add a horizontal offset. Is there a way to increase the `xStep` parameter of the pattern?

I am looking for a pattern like this:

```
|this is the fill text! this is the fill text! this|
|his is the fill text! this is the fill text! this |
|is is the fill text! this is the fill text! this i|
|s is the fill text! this is the fill text! this is|
| is the fill text! this is the fill text! this is |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, so I'll give you two answers:

Either you are looking for the `setXStep()` and `setYStep()` methods in [`PdfPatternPainter`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPatternPainter.html#setXStep(float)). These methods can be used to set the horizontal en vertical interval of the pattern. The result will be a regular pattern.

Or you are looking to change the interval within a shape. For instance: have increasing intervals using the same pattern, resulting in an irregular pattern. That isn't possible in PDF.

**Update:**

Based on your comment and the update in your question, I now understand that this is what you need: [text_pattern.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/text_pattern.pdf)

[image]

We are using *tiled patterns* and the problem you experience is that all tiles are regular. If you want an irregular pattern, you need to use a workaround. Such a workaround is shown in the [TextPattern](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/TextPattern) example.

In this example, I create the pattern like this:

```
// This corresponds with what you have
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont();
String filltext = "this is the fill text! ";
float filltextWidth = bf.getWidthPoint(filltext, 6);
// I create a bigger "tile"
PdfPatternPainter pattern = canvas.createPattern(filltextWidth, 60, filltextWidth, 60);
pattern.beginText();
pattern.setFontAndSize(bf, 6.0f);
// I start with an X offset of 0
float x = 0;
// I add 6 rows of text
// The font is 6, so I used a leading of 10:
for (float y = 0; y < 60; y += 10) {
    // I add the same text twice to each row
    // 1.
    pattern.setTextMatrix(x - filltextWidth, y);
    pattern.showText(filltext);
    // 2.
    pattern.setTextMatrix(x, y);
    pattern.showText(filltext);
    // I change the X offset to 1/6th of the text width
    x += (filltextWidth / 6);
}
pattern.endText();
```

As far as I know, adding the text more than once to the pattern, is the only way to achieve the type of pattern you require.

Comment: I added an example to the question. Is there something like a clipping rectangle so I can fill it by hand with the text pattern?

Comment: Aha, now I understand. I have created something like that before. I'll see if I have time to make an example.

Comment: Thank you! Would be a great addition to your book ;-) In the second edition I have found only colour patterns.